# « En étouffant », « étouffant », « étouffé » ou autre?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Cette nuit je me suis réveillé en étouffant.

> Cette nuit je me suis réveillé étouffant.

> Cette nuit je me suis réveillé étouffé.

> Autres propositions

D’autre idées qui me viennent à l’esprit:

> Je me suis réveillé car j’étouffais.

> Je me suis réveillé car j’étais en train d’étouffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On souhaite indiquer la simultanéité des deux événements. La forme attendue est un gérondif :

> Je me suis réveillé **en étouffant**.

Faire directement suivre un verbe conjugué d'un participe présent, « réveillé étouffant », n'est pas idiomatique.

« Je me suis réveillé étouffé » peut être considéré comme un oxymore, car après s'être étouffé (ou avoir été étouffé), on est à priori mort et donc il y a peu de chance qu'on se réveille...

Les deux dernières phrases sont aussi possibles, elles ajoutent une relation de cause à effet.

Comment: Je savais que seule la première proposition était correcte (hormis les deux dernières que j’ai ajoutées plus tard), je souhaitais juste avoir l’avis d’un expert en langue française sur ce sujet: je suis tombé sur des exemples sur la toile qui s’apparentaient aux deux autres et ils me choquaient…